# Elasticsearch query multiple types with different bool

Tags: elasticsearch, types, boolean-logic

I have an index with 3 different types of content: ['media','group',user'] and I need to do a search at the three at the same type, but requesting some extra parameters that one of them must accomplish before adding to the results list.

Here is my current index data:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "media": {
            "_all": {
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            },
            "properties": {
                "UID": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "include_in_all": false
                },
                "addtime": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "include_in_all": false
                },
                "title": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        "group": {
            "_all": {
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            },
            "properties": {
                "UID": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "include_in_all": false
                },
                "name": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "desc": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "include_in_all": false
                }
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "_all": {
                "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            },
            "properties": {
                "addtime": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "include_in_all": false
                },
                "username": {
                   "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So currently I can make a search on all the index with

```
{
    query: {
      match: {
        _all: {
                "query": "foo",
                "operator": "and"
            }
      }
    }
}
```

and get the results for media, groups or users with the word "foo" on it, which is great, but I need to make it remove all the media on which the user is not the owner of the results. So I guess I need to do a bool query where I set the "must" clause and add the 'UID' variable to whatever the current user ID is.

My problem is how to do this and how to specify that the filter will work just on one type while leaving the others untouched.

I haven't been able to find an answer on the Elastic Search documentation

Comment: Have you looked at the [type filter/query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-type-query.html) and combine that with the already existent filters/queries?

Comment: Yes I did, but my problem is how to apply a condition after the type filter is set, should I just add a "must" after that? My problem is the way how to incorporate that into the rest of the query.
Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you have already. But, in the simplest case a `bool` query with one `must` that is the **type filter** and other `must`s/`should`s that already exist in the query. If they don't, they should be integrated in that `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I was able to accomplish this by following Andrei's comments. I know it is not perfect since I had to add a should with the types "group" and "user", but it fit perfectly with my design since I need to put more filters on those too. Be advice that the search will end up being slower.

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/foo/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool" :
        {
            "must" :
            {
                "query" : {
                    "match" :
                    {
                        "_all":
                        {
                            "query" : "test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter":
            {
                "bool":
                {
                    "should":
                    [{
                        "bool" : {
                            'must':
                            [{
                                "type":
                                {
                                    "value": "media"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                'bool':
                                {
                                    "should" : [
                                        { "term" : {"UID" : 2}}, 
                                        { "term" : {"type" : "public"}}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool" : {
                            "should" : [
                                        { "type" : {"value" : "group"}}, 
                                        { "type" : {"value" : "user"}} 
                                    ]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```